# Remove incorrect binding of composite device to custom driver

Tags: windows, windows-xp, driver, inf, dpinst

Our latest WHQL'ed custom driver has an incorrect entry for one of our upcoming product. The upcoming product is composite device and our WHQL'ed driver has an entry which matches the device ID for the composite device instead of the individual interfaces.

When the new device is connected to machines which have the WHQL'ed driver, the device gets binded to our driver and not to Windows Generic Parent Driver (usbccgp.sys). This prevents the interfaces in the device from being listed.

We could manually fix this by uninstalling the driver for the device and making it to bind to usbccgp.sys driver. In Vista and higher versions, we could delete the driver binaries at the time of uninstall. But there is no direct way to completely delete the driver binaries in XP. This makes it very difficult to cleanly uninstall the driver

Can this be fixed using an uninstaller? What is the best way to fix the affected machine in an automated way?

Answer (score 0):

Download the Windows Driver Development Kit (Win DDK) and locate the devcon.exe executable for your architecture. Then, from an elevated command prompt:

```
devcon.exe find =usb
```

To list all of your current devices.

```
devcon.exe -r remove =usb *YOUR_HARDWARE_ID*
```

Will complete disassociate the device and driver from the target machine. If you have trouble getting the hardware id you can blow away all your USB drivers and let Windows auto-detect them after reboot.

```
devcon.exe -r remove =usb *
```

Extreme, yes. Effective, yes. We work with virtual comm ports all day and our test machines often experience your same issue. This technique has yet to fail.